# Synonyms and Redundant Tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

Post synonyms and redundant tags here (one tag set per answer) for us to ponder and potentially edit out of existence.

Comment: Here's a newer meta thread on the same topic: http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/q/382/2660

Answer (score 5):

- MSSQL
- SQLSERVER

I think we can all agree that generally those two mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

synonyms

- dual
- oracle

because I don't think anyone else has a "dual" in their implementation do they?

Comment: Yes, 'dual' should be rewritten as a 'oracle' because it's not a preferred access point ... but that's not technically a synonym.

Comment: @Joe all I mean is that when someone writes `SELECT ... FROM DUAL ...` I instantly read "Oracle development" as one of the attributes of whatever problem is being discussed.

Comment: In a thesaurus, the relationship you're describing would be `USE` or `PT` (preferred term), not `SN` (synonym).  `SN` means that the terms are interchangable, as would `ET` (equivalent term; they're interchangable for our purposes), `SP` (spelling variant), etc.

Comment: @Joe ~ I just kind of meant tag-synonym. I'm sure you're correct tho.

Comment: MySQL has `dual`, too (I guess as an attempt for compatibility with Oracle)

Comment: How interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Redundant tag:

```
sql-server-2008r2
sql-server-2008-r2
```

I propose that we remove the **sql-server-2008r2** tag as it had only 3 entries as opposed to the 700+ entries for the sql-server-2008-r2 tag.

Answer (score 3):

## Tag <kbd>regular-expression</kbd>

This tag could/should be the base tag for <kbd>regex</kbd>

#### Usage Guidance for Tag

> `<empty>`

## Tag <kbd>regex</kbd>

This tag should be the synonym for regular-expression as per the quick info:

> a shortening of the phrase "regular expression". A regex is typically a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern,

#### Usage Guidance for Tag

> The term REGEX is a shortening of the phrase "regular expression".  A regex is typically a sequence of characters that forms a search pattern, mainly for use in pattern matching with strings.

Answer (score 2):

synonym?

- no-value
- empty-string

The hard part here is that there's also the matter of

- null

which the three of these form a triplet around which most people have a hard time.

---

Personally I say vote this particular answer down. But I'm asking for community guidance, I'm not sure at all.

Comment: I say keep the null tag and delete the others.

Comment: @Larry is that a joke? damn you text only transcripts for not carrying 90% of communication inherently!!

Comment: I'm serious. We're DBA's here, and DBA's spell no value "N-U-L-L".

Comment: But you admit that developers and the like (meaning everyone not a DBA) reads "empty string" as "no value" right?

Comment: @drachenstern: Sure, so maybe the answer is that the others are synonyms pointing to null. Or are we expecting our audience to consist mostly of non-DBA's?

Comment: And now we come to the dilemma of my posting this particular answer/question in the first place :| ... I think the three are a good synonym, allowing DBAs to assist the non-DBAs based on tag-sets on the front page, etc. ~ Remember, deleting the tag just encourages it to get re-created later. Creating a tag-synonym lets the system correlate answers on our behalf.

Comment: @drachenstern: I agree, then, that a synonym is what we want.

Answer (score 1):

synonyms:

- slow log
- logging
- logs

I'm sure there will be others. I don't know that they necessarily *in our context* mean the same things...

Answer (score 0):

Merge `ssis` and `ssis2008` and just use `ssis`. For version specific features, the sql version tag can be included.

Answer (score -2):

How about:

- sql-server-2008

  - Used for all versions of MS Sql Server 2008
  - OR
  - Only the R1 release of MS Sql Server 2008
- sql-server-2008-R2

  - For problems specifically targeting MS Sql Server 2008 R2

I know they're not the same, but there's over 200 questions with 2008 and only 12 or so with R2. At this point, can't these two tags be merged/synonymed??

Comment: What benefit does merging give us on these two tags?

Comment: I would think it would give us all the benefits of merging any two tags.  [Searches](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2008-R2) become simpler; deciding which tag to use becomes simpler; you help prevent [tag overload](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/request-to-run-job-dbxxxxx-refused-error-in-merge-replication), etc.

Comment: I meant, there is a difference between R1 and R2. Do you think we should reversion so that non-R2 Q become called out for the fact that they're non R2? Does everyone just assume that 2008 means R2?

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense.  ;)  Unfortunately, I don't know what everyone assumes.  However, looking at the 11 R2 posts, it seems that none of them are asking questions that are specifically R2.  I haven't looked at the 216 non-R2 questions, but I would think that the vast majority of them would apply to R2. If the differences are too great between R1 and R2, I wouldn't mind leaving R2.  It just seems unused by comparison.

Comment: And so it may be. Let's leave this Q up for a bit and see what support it garners.

Comment: I think SQL-Server questions shouls have a `[sql-server]` tag and a specific per version tag, 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008-R2 or 2012. We'll have more questions tagged with 2012 in the future but that doesn't mean that they need specific features of 2012 to be solved. I don't think you agree to merge all the sql-server versions tags?